# Trigger a custom event to add jquery to a dynamic element created by a plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am a beginner at jquery, and I am trying to change my websites header's colors depending on which slide the metaslider is being shown. 
I understand that to style a dynamic element through jquery I must use an event listener, and the below code works fine if I just use a 'click' or 'mouseenter' but I need the header colors to change on simply loading the page without waiting for the user to click or hover. So I tried to do this by creating a pseudo event -

```
    var e = jQuery.Event( "mouseover mouseout" );


    $(document).on('jQuery(document).trigger( e )', '.flex-active-slide', function(){
            $("li.slide-755.ms-image.flex-active-slide").closest("#pagewrap").find("#site-logo a").css('cssText', 'color: #0000ff!important');
    });
```

Any help explained simply would be really appreciated as I'm a beginner. Thank you!!

Comment: what version of flex slider is being used there?

Comment: I was using flex slider 3.7.0, and now 3.7.2, updating the plugin didn't change anything

Comment: There are flex callbacks for when a slide is changed. You could use those instead of the mouseover and mouseout evemts

Comment: The slide interval is set to one hour (to keep it as the same slide unless you refresh), so the slide will not change after loading once

Answer (score 0):

This callback fires whenever an animation has finished and adds a class of "myClass" to whatever element(s) within the slider have a class of "flex-active-slide"

```js
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    after: function(){alert("hello you can add your js here for each slide change")},
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.0/flexslider.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=596945d5421b">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=596945d5421b">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.0/jquery.flexslider.min.js"></script>


<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below did it for me

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){/*my code here */}
```

this way every time the page loads, I edit the css, instead of using jquery event listeners.